# Twitter - Using the "tweet link" button, how do I get the resulting tweet link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, twitter-oauth

So I followed the instructions [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) and have the resulting code of

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

My question is that how do I get the resulting tweet url that contains the link? I have tried using [Web Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents) by adding the following code below the first two above:

```
function debugEvent(intent_event) {
    console.log(intent_event);
    alert('I am here');
}
twttr.events.bind('tweet',    debugEvent);
```

but the function debugEgent doesn't seem to be firing.

Any suggestions on how to get the resulting URL of the tweet? I will be storing the link into a database, you see.